# Customize the look of the navigation bar in iOS 5 SDK

Tags: xcode4, ios5, uinavigationcontroller, uinavigationbar

In the iOS 5 SDK, how do I customize the look of the navigation bar within my navigation controller?

I had added this in my AppDelegate.m file based on a tutorial I found, but it did not seem to work:

```
@implementation UINavigationBar (Background)

-(void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    UIImage *image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"top_shadow.png"];
    [image drawInRect:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.frame.size.width, self.frame.size.height)];
}

@end
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

in IOS5 now you can change the background without creating a category

Check This URL

http://www.mladjanantic.com/setting-custom-background-for-uinavigationbar-what-will-work-on-ios5-and-ios4-too/